# How to adapt the LBFGS algorithm to accept a different data input parameter in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, optimization, scala

I´m trying to use the LBFGS algorithm to minimize the parameters of a model used for Customer Life Time Value analysis (https://github.com/CamDavidsonPilon/lifetimes). The lifetimes lib in python uses a minimize function that has the data arrays as input parameters. The format is something like:

```
date,id
2014-03-08 00:00:00,0
2014-05-21 00:00:00,1
2014-03-14 00:00:00,2
```

We need to implement this same function in scala, but the implementation available here (https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.2.0/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/optimization/LBFGS.scala) has a sligthly different format for the data input:

```
   * @param data - Input data for L-BFGS. RDD of the set of data examples, each of
   *               the form (label, [feature values]).
```

Question is, how could I change the scala implementation to accept the data as just plain arrays or in the format given by the lifetimes lib in python?